# can we create a view on procedure,function,trigger,package?

Tags: sql, oracle, object, view, plsql

I am new in SQL , going through some assignments of view.
I have some questions regarding view that is :

can we create a view on procedure,function,trigger,package or sequence , index,synonym?
if yes then how?

Comment: have you checked the Oracle documentation?

Comment: tell us what you want to do first

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example of a view based on a FUNCTION (note: not a PIPELINED function, though it could have been):

```
create or replace type dept_t is object (deptno number, dname varchar2(10));

create or replace type dept_tab_t is table of dept_t;

create or replace function depts_fun 
return dept_tab_t
is 
  l_dept_tab dept_tab_t := dept_tab_t();
begin
  for r in (select deptno, dname from dept)
  loop
    l_dept_tab.extend;
    l_dept_tab(l_dept_tab.count) := dept_t(r.deptno, r.dname);
  end loop;

  return l_dept_tab;
end;
/

create view depts_view as
select * from table (depts_fun);

select * from depts_view;
```

I'm not saying it is useful or well done, just that it is possible!

Of course, I could have (and probably would in a real system) put the function in a PACKAGE, so a view can be based on a package function too.

So the (complete?) list of objects you can create a view over is:

- tables
- views
- synonyms
- materialized views
- stand-alone functions that return a table type
- package functions that return a table type

Comment: we can say that views can be created over anything that can stay in place of `T` in the expression E = `select something from T` where E is valid ?

Answer (score 1):

A `view` can be created over a `table` or another `view`. `Synonyms` are included because they are only a different name of a `table`. (a `view` is a view of **data**)

You can't create a view over code (`procedure,function,trigger,package`) or a `sequence`.

As special case is [PIPELINED functions](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11%3a%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:19481671347143), as Glenn remarked, wich produce a set of data, syntax is:

```
select something from TABLE(pipelined_function())
```

but that's not a view :)

Comment: I guess some proc/function results can be queried as tables. Pipelined functions or an example like this: CREATE FUNCTION junk RETURN NUMBER IS BEGIN RETURN 2; END;
SELECT junk() from dual

Comment: In your example selected object is `dual` wich is a table. Pipelined functions are a different thing, and are not a views. The syntax is `select something from TABLE(pipe_function())`

Comment: I'm just a bit hesitant on saying we can't create a view over code. I would consider the pipelined table example as a view over code. That's all I'm trying to get at. I think there are non-pipelined examples as well so long as your return is a nested table.

Comment: I've added to answer the pipelined functions. Thanks.

Comment: IMO if you're creating something that doesn't involve `CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW...` then you're not creating a view.  IMO if it doesn't show up when you execute `SELECT * FROM DBA_VIEWS` (or USER_VIEWS or whatever) then it's not a view.  YMMV.

Comment: A function doesn't have to be PIPELINED to be used in TABLE() expression; it just has to return a table type.

Comment: ..."but that's not a view :)" `create view v as select something from TABLE(pipelined_function())` - now it is ;-)

Comment: @TonyAndrews You are funny :) My assertion stands because just does not make sense to have view over code. Your answer is very good and offer more details to understand the concepts. We can say more generaly that a view can be created over anything you can `select` from it :)

Comment: @Florin, I have worked on systems where they had views over code.  I agree with you that it wasn't terribly sensible!